# FFMpeg crop filter doesn't change orientation

Tags: video-editor, ffmpeg, quicktime

I am trying to crop a portrait video of 1280x720 to 568x320 so that the video will be displayed in landscape view (16:9). I am using the following command

```
ffmpeg -i VID_1438833296.mp4 -vf crop=568:320:0:0 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

The video gets cropped properly but when I view it in quick time or Android device it still displays in the portrait mode instead of landscape mode.

**The quicktime inspector shows Format size as 568x320 (Landscape) but current size is 350x621 (Portrait):**

[image]

Comment: Please include the complete console output from your command and [properly format](http://video.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) the command and console output.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is two things:

1)your video is portrait but stored as a landscape matrix and ffmpeg is applying autorotate so that all players natively display it in what ffmpeg thinks is the correct orientation.

2) the video has a PAL DV aspect ratio of ~1.09, so after the autorotation and aspect ratio correction, 568 x 320 is autorotated to 320 x 568 with 1.09 scaler being applied to both W and H.

Try this, instead:

```
ffmpeg -i VID_1438833296.mp4 -noautorotate -vf setsar=1,crop=568:320:0:0 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Crop filter is not designed to change orientation, use another filter to change orientation of cropped video.